# How to make $watch working on different field of ng-model

Tags: angularjs, watch

On my html page i have 5 6 different field for form

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit.TIME"placeholder="Time" maxlength="30" ng-required="true" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit.NAME" placeholder="Time" maxlength="30" ng-required="true" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit.Place"placeholder="Time" maxlength="30" ng-required="true" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edit.LASTNAME" placeholder="Time" maxlength="30" ng-required="true" />
```

How i can call each ng-model with $ watch. If any thing change $ watch will show change value. on My controller side

```
    $scope.old.NAME="ABC";   
    $scope.$watch('edit', function (Value) {          
        if ($scope.old.NAME != $scope.edit.NAME) {  
            $scope.old.NAME.append($scope.edit.NAME)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call watch with true as the third argument:

```
$scope.$watch('edit', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal);
}, true);
```

Comment: If i try like this one it work but i want to call any change in any of ng-model   $scope.$watch('edit.NAME', function (Value) {          
        if ($scope.old.NAME != $scope.edit.NAME) {  
            $scope.old.NAME.append($scope.edit.NAME)
        }

Comment: Then you should be able to change `'edit'` to `'edit.NAME'`... does that work?

Comment: Yes that works . but i wan to use edit only so that if user enter on any field my $watch show work

Comment: @DeveshKhosla Yes, that's what my answer does.